# Configuration parameters for PostgreSQL ODBC driver connection string

Tags: postgresql, odbc

I am currently extracting data from PostgreSQL using its own [ODBC driver](https://odbc.postgresql.org/).
The basic parameter described on [Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql-odbc-driver-psqlodbc/) work so far, but I was not able to find which other parameters are supported.
The documentation of the [Devart ODBC Driver](https://www.devart.com/odbc/postgresql/docs/connection_options.htm) also supports the field `Schema`, which does not seem to work with the one of the PostgreSQL project.

Last but not least, there is a list in the documentation of the ODBC driver [listing connection keywords](https://odbc.postgresql.org/docs/config-opt.html), but these do not match the ones in [Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql-odbc-driver-psqlodbc/) either.

Is there any resource or standard describing the Connection String parameters I missed?

Answer (score 0):

You should trust the documentation of the product rather than an unrelated site.

If you want to set the `search_path` with a connection option, you can use the `Pqopt` parameter like this

```
pqopt={search_path=myschema,public}
```

**Disclaimer:** I didn't test it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This already brought me some way forward. Concerning the search path, I tried it out and then read in the right part of the docs after knowing what to look for. the following option worked: `pqopt={options=-csearch_path=myschema,public}`.

Concerning the main question: This means that the Connection Parameter overview from the Postgresql project is indeed authoritative although some undocumented parameters are supported? (eg. `Pwd`, `Uid`) see: https://odbc.postgresql.org/docs/config-opt.html

Comment: Hm, yes, I would consider the documentation authoritative. But as you found out, the information concerning `pqopt` was not quite accurate, so it obviously contains bugs. Did you test if `pwd` and `uid` work or are just fabrications of that connectionstrings web site?

Comment: The connection string contained `Uid` and `Pwd` before and this part of the configuration worked fine. I tried `Username` and `Password`, as described in the table as well, and it also worked. So both parameters seem to be implemented, but only on is mentioned in the docs.